# C#.net db connection with sql server 2005 MDF file

Tags: c#

After creating the setup file in c#.net WPF application, couldnot connect with the sqlserver 2005 MDF file.

The setup file is including the sqlserver MDF file.

plz tell me, what is connection problem?

Comment: Can you include the exact error message that you received in the question please? Any answers offered with so little information would be informed guesswork.

Comment: Maybe also show the snippet of code that shows how you are trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess (see comments on your question): You're trying to use the "user instance" feature that was introduced in SQL Server 2005? Then the SQL Server 2005 needs to be installed on the target machine as well - maybe only the Express edition. As long as you don't install the SQL Server there's no way you get a connection to your shipped MDF file.